# search an item by name and display the content in another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to display an item information in gridview from data base by using it name , and i want the gridview to be in another page 
i tried this code,,but it didn't work

in the first page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public string txt
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the actual name if it is not null.
            return TextBox1.Text ?? string.Empty;
        }

    }
    }
```

in the second page

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=FATIMAH;Initial Catalog=makeup;Integrated Security=True");
        string find = "select * from product where(name like '%' +@name+ '%')";
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(find, con);

        comm.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = txt;
        con.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = comm;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "name");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass parameter to another page using QueryString.  onclick event of button on First page do this:-

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string search_word = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
        Response.Redirect("~/secondpage.aspx?srch_word=" + search_word);
    }
```

and on second page request the querystring:-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string search = Request.QueryString["srch_word"];   
      //execute sql query to perform search operation
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks off to me. Try `"select * from product where name like '%@name%'"`

Also for your parameters you can just `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", nameVariable);`

Not sure why you would need to specify the type in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is not the SQL query, your problem is passing parameter to another page.
for this reason you can do it in at least 4 different ways.

1. Send Text by query string
2. Pass it via Post Data
3. Pass it via Cookie
4. Send it via Session

in this case you can use query string, but you have to care about security issue.
BTW, it depends on how you redirect to 2th page.